# Is there an efficient way to monitor the progress of a task remotely?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

Recently, I've been running Mathematica packages on a remote cluster using SSH (using, e.g. the command

```
nohup nice math -noprompt -run "<<myPackage.m" > myOutput &
```

so that the output of the code is captured into the file `myOutput`.) This is particularly useful if the package contains output on the status of the computation, so that that output can easily be read from the `myOutput` file. However, this doesn't work for the usage of the function `Monitor`. For example, suppose the package code was very simple:

```
Monitor[Table[i+j,{i,10},{j,10}],{i,j}];
```

The output would not be stored in the file `myOutput`. This makes sense, as the cell is being updated and the output file will only capture true output e.g. those associated with `Print`. My question is: is there any efficient/easy way to obtain the status of an ongoing computation that is being performed remotely? One could always turn the code into a `Do` loop for example and insert `Print` statements accordingly, but I'm wondering if there is something more efficient or robust like `Monitor` that can be adjusted to update the status of a computation at a desired frequency.